# scripts that runs a programme with enter

Tags: bash, shell

so I want to run a a interactive program from a script that would hit simple hit enter.

I am thinking of the scripts to be

"\n"| ./myprogramme

is it right? Thank you.

Comment: The program expects to read input and you just want to send an empty string to it? One line? More than one line? Are there prompts you need to answer? Does the program read from standard input?

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably get: `\n: command not found`

You need a command that outputs a newline:

```
echo | myprogramme
```

or use a here-doc

```
myprogramme <<END

END
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `yes` program to repeatedly output a string to another program:

```
yes '' | ./my_program
```

It will output newlines as long as the receiving program is reading from standard input.